# unix filename pattern in sftp command prompt

Tags: bash, unix, pattern-matching

Please help, I am new to unix,

I want to read file which are available before 130000(hhmiss), meaning file from 00 hours to 13 hours.

```
XYZ_20170504_{00,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12}[0-5][0-9][0-5][0-9].csv
```

OR

```
XYZ_20170504_{13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23}[0-5][0-9][0-5][0-9]
```

Double digit pattern matching is not working for my case.

Examples

```
File pattern 1: XYZ_DATE_TIME.csv
```

I want to mget files from sftp server where twice a day.

```
String_yyyymmdd_hhmiss.csv
XYZ_20170514_035959.csv
```

OR

```
XYZ_20170514_165959.csv
```

Comment: can you add the terminal output so we can see what is going on?

Comment: sftp> mget XYZ_20170504_(0[0-9]|1[0-2])[0-5][0-9][0-5][0-9].csv
File "/folder/XYZ_20170504_(0[0-9]|1[0-2])[0-5][0-9][0-5][0-9].csv" not found.

Answer (score 0):

First of all in your question, i can see an error in your search regarding the dates.

Your regex is looking for this

`XYZ_20170504_`

and your file contains this

`XYZ_20170514_`

So obviously these will never match. I think this is more like what you need

**000000 to 125959**

```
XYZ_20170514_(0[0-9]|1[0-2])[0-5][0-9][0-5][0-9].csv
```

OR

**130000 to 235959**

```
XYZ_20170514_(1[3-9]|2[0-3])[0-5][0-9][0-5][0-9].csv
```

Also this is a relatively quick fix, only looking for matches relating to the time. You should also look to further improve this so that you fully sure you are matching correctly on the dates also.

For your own reference there are many tools available online to help you with your regular expressions and pattern matching. The one i favour most is [regex101](https://regex101.com), however there are many others available too.

Comment: Thank you for replying, i tried the solution but things are still not working :
File 1:  XYZ_20170504_160002.csv
File 2:  XYZ_20170504_033002.csv

sftp> mget XYZ_20170504_(0[0-9]|1[0-2])[0-5][0-9][0-5][0-9].csv
File "/folder/XYZ_20170504_(0[0-9]|1[0-2])[0-5][0-9][0-5][0-9].csv" not found.

Comment: Although regex you provided is passing the test for inputs in the online link you provided, somehow not working above. One case working fine is sftp>mget XYZ_20170504_*.csv